# How to convert JPG image to PNG in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, png

For an app I have some jpg images I want to upload to a server. The server only accepts png images so I was wondering how to convert these images to .pngs.
I found one (not so popular) module: https://github.com/voxmarkets/react-native-image-converter but after installing it (bot manually and automatically) on android it didn't work.
Are there any other approaches?